# modify `sed` to remove exact tag from within a string

Tags: regex, string, sed

I am trying to remove a variable tag that I have on my data with `grep` and `sed`.
The data that I have looks like this:

```
Please_VB make_VB it_PRP in_IN a_DT range_NN of_IN colored_JJ and_CC precise_JJR Skin_NN tone_NN shades_VBZ
```

My goal is to extract only those words that have a tag of `_NNS`, `_NNP`, `_NN`, `_JJ` and `_JJR`. For a desired result of:

```
range
colored
precise
skin
tone
```

The `grep` and `sed` that I am using right now is the following:

```
grep -oh "\w*_\(JJ\|NN\)\w*" test_file.txt | sed 's/[_JJ\|_NN\|_JJR\|_NNP\|_NNS]//g'
```

The result of that command line, however, is:

```
range
colored
precise
kin
tone
```

It correctly extracts the correct words with the `grep`, but the `sed` is removing all corresponding letters, rather than just the exact tag of `_NX` or `_JX`.
Is there any way that I can make the `sed` more precise to remove ONLY the exact  tag as specified rather than any letter that is also within the tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use POSIX `grep` (that doesn't support `-P` option) with `cut`:

```
grep -Eo '\w*_(NN[PS]?|JJR?)' file | cut -d_ -f1

range
colored
precise
Skin
tone
```

`cut` is used to strip off part after first underscore.

Answer (score 2):

You may extract those value with `grep` and a PCRE regex with a lookahead:

```
grep -oP "\w+(?=_(JJR?|NN[PS]?))"
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/9NwCFE)

*Details*:

- `\w+` - 1 or more word characters (letter, digits or an underscore)...
- `(?=_(JJR?|NN[PS]?))` - that are followed with

  - `_` - an underscore and...
  - `(JJR?|NN[PS]?)`  - `JJ`, `JJR`, `NN`, `NNP` or `NNS` substrings.

The `P` option in `-oP` will enforce the use of PCRE egnine, and `o` will get you the matches only.